# Question reguarding initial value problem ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> $$\mathrm{x = c_1cos( t) + c_2sin(t)}$$ 
>   is a two-parameter
>   family of solutions of the second-order DE $$x'' + x = 0.$$ 
>   Find a solution of the second-order IVP consisting of this differential
>   equation and the given initial conditions:
>   $$x(0)=1 $$
>   $$x'(0)=8$$

I found the derivative

$$x' =  - c_1\sin (t) + c_2\cos (t)$$

given $$x(0) =  - 1
$$

I solved for $c_1$

$$c_1 =  - 1$$ when $x=0$

I then plugged in $c_1$ to $x'(0)$ in order to solve for $c_2$, but $\sin(t)$ at $0$ would be zero.

Plugging in $0$ to $\cos(t)$ would just be $c_2$. The Problem gives

$x'(0)=8$, so if $c_2$ is $c_2(1)$, then how can $c_2$ be equal to $7$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of question generally defines a $2\times2$ linear system of equations. However, in this specific example, it so happens that one of the terms in both equations vanishes when evaluated at $0$, which makes our life easier.

We calculate
$$ x(0) = c_1\cos(0)+c_2\sin(0) = c_1. $$
Then, because $c_2\sin(0) =0$, we see immediately that $c_1=1=x(0)$.

Next, just as you calculated, $x'(t) = -c_1\sin(t) + c_2\cos(t)$. Now, in a similar manner to the previous case, $c_1\sin(0) = 0$, so evaluating at $t=0$ gives
$$ x'(0) = -c_1\sin(0) + c_2 \cos(0) = c_2.$$

From the condition $x'(0) = 8$, it follows that $c_2 = 8$.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer and insight!

Answer (score 1):

Solution of $$x'' + x = 0$$is $$x(t)=a_1 \cos t+a_2 \sin t$$

Here $x'(t)=-a_1 \sin t+a_2 \cos t$

The given conditions are $x(0)=1 \quad \text{and }\quad x'(0)=8$

$x(0)=1\implies a_1\cos 0 + a_2 \sin 0=1\implies a_1=1$

$x'(0)=8\implies -a_1\sin 0 +a_2 \cos 0 =8\implies a_2 =8$

Hence $x(t)= \cos t+8 \sin t$

Comment: Thankyou so much!

Comment: You are most welcome